# Google Groups in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

I have a GoogleSite binded to a Blogger account, and a GoogleGroups account (so googleish of me)

Google webmaster tools adds without any trouble the site ant the blog but complains when I try to add my GoogleGroup. The app asks me to validate the ownership of the googlegroup i've created by injecting an htmp into the page or adding a meta tag.

But googlegroups does not allow any of the options requested...

Any known workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that's not possible. Google groups is a discussion site, so they you can't do much to customise it. Sites and blogs are designed so that you can change the look of pages, inserting tags or scripts.